# How can one process access foreign TIB?

Tags: windows, winapi

Is it possible (and how) to access Thread Information Block of a thread of some another process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible.

The first step is to get the adress of the Thread Information Block by using the [NtQueryInformationThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684283%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function with *ThreadInformationClass* set to [ThreadBasicInformation](http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/UserMode/Undocumented%20Functions/NT%20Objects/Thread/THREAD_INFORMATION_CLASS.html#ThreadBasicInformation). The [THREAD_BASIC_INFORMATION](http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/UserMode/Structures/THREAD_BASIC_INFORMATION.html) structure contains a pointer to the TEB of the thread. Then you can use [ReadProcessMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680553%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [WriteProcessMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681674%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in order to read or modify the content of the TEB.