# How to check how much from heap and from stack my program is using?

Tags: c, visual-studio, memory-management, heap-memory

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 7 - 64 bit machine.
I'm writing a program on C.
How can I check how much heap and stack storage my program is using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Heap consumption , internally & externally ( programatically ) :** You can use GetProcessMemory function : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683219.aspx

**Heap consumption , externally & non programatically :** You can use MS Technet`s  VMMap : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/vmmap.aspx

**Stack consumption , internally ( programatically ) :** You can use Windows thread information block : https://stackoverflow.com/a/1747249/1996740

**Stack consumption , externally & programatically :** Here is a nice answer showing how you can access an external thread`s thread information block : https://stackoverflow.com/a/8751576/1996740